# Javascript rewriting an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, dictionary, arraylist

I have two arrays that are dynamic which could change at any time.
For example:

```
var vehicleColor = "red,green,blue,white".split(",");
var vehicleType = "Truck,Car,Bus".split(",");
```

How can I incorporate these arrays to make a javascript array in this format for my graph.

```
var links = [
    {source: vehicleColor[0], target: vehicleType[0]},
    {source: vehicleColor[1], target: vehicleType[0]},  
    {source: vehicleColor[2], target: vehicleType[0]},
    {source: vehicleColor[3], target: vehicleType[0]},  
    {source: vehicleColor[0], target: vehicleType[1]},
    {source: vehicleColor[1], target: vehicleType[1]},
    etc...
]
```

Basically I need an array that loops through all of the elements in both arrays but creating a separate line for each one.

I've tried:

```
links = links.map(x => ({source:vehicleColor, target:vehicleType}));
```

but this doesn't get me each element in a separate line.

The map method gives me this output

```
var links = [
    {source: ["red","green","blue","white"], target: ["Truck","Bus","Car"]},
]
```

Comment: What is links? Is it important to or related some how to `vehicleColor` or `vehicleType`?

Comment: @PatrickEvans Links is an array I'm using to create my graph with d3. It is not related to vehicleColor or vehicleType

Comment: Is `links` meant to be **live**? E.g., if you create your `links` array of objects, then change `vehicleColor[1]`, do you expect `links[1].source` and `links[5].source` to change without anything explicitly updating `links`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use nested loops:

```js
var vehicleColor = "red,green,blue,white".split(",");
var vehicleType = "Truck,Car,Bus".split(",");

var links = [];
for (var i = 0; i < vehicleType.length; ++i) {
  var type =  vehicleType[i];
  for (var j = 0; j < vehicleColor.length; ++j) {
    links.push({
      source: type,
      target: vehicleColor[j]
    });
  }
}

console.log(links);
```

Comment: *(If the outer loop is on `vehicleColor`, hit refresh. I got them swapped 'round initially.)*

Comment: your code currently prints links to the console. I'm just trying to change my current links array to this. Is there anyway to do that other than maps?

Comment: @Akshay - I don't understand the question. Writing them out to the console is just to show what's in `links`. The main point is that `links` is set to the array of objects you describe, not the `console.log`.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a recursive function which separates all key/value pairs and build a new cartesian product by iterating the values, if an array with objects call `getCartesian` again and build new objects.

```js
function getCartesian(object) {
    return Object.entries(object).reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
        var temp = [];
        r.forEach(s =>
            (Array.isArray(v) ? v : [v]).forEach(w =>
                (w && typeof w === 'object' ? getCartesian(w) : [w]).forEach(x =>
                    temp.push(Object.assign({}, s, { [k]: x }))
                )
            )
        );
        return temp;
    }, [{}]);
}

var data = { source: ["red", "green", "blue", "white"], target: ["Truck", "Bus", "Car"] };

console.log(getCartesian(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: ...or...the simple, obvious way: nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

I used a foreach and map to get the desired result

```js
var vehicleColor = "red,green,blue,white".split(",");
var vehicleType = "Truck,Car,Bus".split(",");

let res = [];
vehicleColor.forEach((color) => {
     res = res.concat(vehicleType.map((type) => {
       return {'source': color, 'target': type}
    }))
 })
 
 console.log(res)
```

Comment: your code currently prints links to the console. I'm just trying to change my current links array to this. Is there anyway to do that other than maps?

Answer (score 0):

You may run two run two loops. For example when taking each color as a constant run the complete loop for vehicle, then repeat the same for another color

```js
var vehicleColor = "red,green,blue,white".split(",");
var vehicleType = "Truck,Car,Bus".split(",");

let links = [];
vehicleColor.forEach(function(item) {
  vehicleType.forEach(function(ve) {
    links.push({
      source: item,
      target: ve
    })
  })
})
console.log(links)
```

Comment: your code currently prints links to the console. I'm just trying to change my current links array to this. Is there anyway to do that other than maps?